# censorship and tbb exit nodes.

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, censorship

The three gifts that tor and tbb give are anonymity, privacy and no censorship or so I believed. For last few days/weeks I have been observing that quite a few domains don't work on tor anymore. While part of the answer may lie in domain takedowns and I suspect many are, but does censorship apply to rules of exit node. Just for e.g. let's say I'm sitting in Sri Lanka, using tor circuits out of any of the 140 countries where tor has a presence, for e.g. say using Germany as the exit node by chance. Now would censorship of Germany be applied to the requst for a site or am I mis-understanding something ?  I do know that in-between it's all encrypted communication through and through (https) but still is some leakage possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the exit node the exit node's local ISP filters may apply - like to any other network client in that place: yes, from the point of ISP an exit node is a client. In your example a censorship of Germany will be applied, a censorship of Sri Lanka - won't be appled.